# Como estilizar texto dentro da tag code?

Tags: html, css, html5, scss

Eu gostaria de deixar um trecho de código estilizado assim como é nas ide mas não sei como fazer isso, procurei aqui e não encontrei nada a respeito, eu gostaria de deixar algo parecido com o que está na imagem abaixo com os nomes das variáveis, função, parâmetros, etc. com uma cor definida, ao invés de só o texto com a cor preta padrão da tag code.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Comment: Considere usar uma lib. Existem várias: [Prism](https://prismjs.com/) ou [HighlightJS](https://highlightjs.org/) são exemplos disso.

Answer (score -1):

Após seu comentário, entendi do que se trata.

Se o que você quer é identar para exibir essa informação para o usuário final, recomendo utilizar essa lib do JS que o próprio github, slack e outros utilizam,
a [Highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js#highlightjs), aqui também tem a sua [documentação](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

Existem algumas formas de utilizar, como é possível ver no tutorial do [getting the library](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js#getting-the-library). Caso não use nenhum framework, pode importar direto da CDN que a lib é disponibilizada. Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa, só comentar.

Comment: Opa, boa noite, a imagem que inseri foi apenas um exemplo, eu gostaria mesmo era de saber como estilizar as variáveis, funções, etc. mas desde já, obrigado